# curl hangs on centos 7 ec2 instance

Tags: centos, curl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run the following bash command:

```
seq 1 200 | parallel --eta -j 16 'echo  url: {} && curl -s -o /dev/null https://www.google.com'
```

Towards the end of the run, the command hangs, somewhere along the way one or more of the curl commands fails.

If I reduce the number of parallel processes to 4, then the command always completes. Trying with 5 and 6 parallel commands sometimes works and sometimes fails. With 8 it always fails.

I can get similar results by simply running a series of commands in a shell script like this:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null https://www.google.com &
curl -s -o /dev/null https://www.google.com &
.
. (with 32 curl commands running in the background at once)
.
curl -s -o /dev/null https://www.google.com &
wait
```

I was originally running into this on an EC2 M4.4xlarge. Upgrading to M5.4xlarge had no effect, the problem still persists.

I have performed a yum upgrade.

```
uname -a
```

Returns:

3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64

It's clearly a resource issue of some type, but I can not determine the cause.

Can someone suggest what kernel parameters to tweak?

Comment: Did you consider Google limiting the number of concurrent requests from a single IP? Google's APIs usually allow for a maximum of 10 requests per second (I don't know if this is the same for the `www.google.com` web site though).

Comment: Next time, try this on your own local site, so you have control on every part of the chain

Comment: Does it stop at the same number? `parallel -k ...` is your friend to determine that.